# Is it possible to cast Func<object, object> to Func<T1, TResult> using reflection without Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to create an implementation of Autofac-style automatic delegate factories that would work with AOT (specifically, Unity3d and IL2CPP).

Main problem that I ran into is inability to cast from `Func<object, object>` to `Func<T1, TResult>` in the runtime.

Is there any way you can do that with reflection, but avoiding generating IL code in the runtime (i.e. without Reflection.Emit)?

```
Func<object, object> func = delegate (object arg1)
{
    return arg1.ToString() + " bar";
};

Func<string, string> func2;
func2 = (Func<string, string>)func;


Console.WriteLine(func2("foo")); // "foo bar" ? :(
// System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Object]' to type 'System.Func`2[System.String,System.String]'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible to cast a Func of one type to a Func of another type. Depending on the use case, you could wrap one in the other to achieve your desired result, as demonstrated below.

```
Func<object, object> func = delegate (object arg1)
{
    return arg1.ToString() + " bar";
};

// Wrap func with a call by func2 to get the desired casting.
Func<string, string> func2 = o => func(o) as string;

Console.WriteLine(func2("foo"));
```

Comment: `delegate` keyword? In 2018??